# How to make sum with variable finite number of elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

This is one of the first things I try to code in python (and any programming language) and my first question here, so I hope I provide everything neccessary to help me.

I have upper triangular matrix and I need to solve system of equations Wx=y, where W (3x3 matrix) and y (vector) are given. I cannot use numpy.linalg functions, so I try to implement [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_and_back_substitution), but backwards of course.
After several failed attempts, I limited my task to 3x3 matrix. Without loop, code looks like this:

```
x[0,2]=y[2]/W[2,2]
x[0,1]=(y[1]-W[1,2]*x[0,2])/W[1,1]
x[0,0]=(y[0]-W[0,2]*x[0,2]-W[0,1]*x[0,1])/W[0,0]
```

Now, every new sum contains more elements, which are schematic, but nevertheless need to be defined somehow. I suppose there must be sum function in numpy, but not linalg, which does such things, but I cannot find it.
My newest, partial "attempt" begins with something like this:

```
n=3
for k in range(n):
    for i in range(n-k-1):
        x[0,n-k-1]=y[n-k-1]/W[n-k-1,n-k-1]
```

Which, of course, contains only first element of each sum.
I would be thankful for any assistance.

Example I am working on:

```
y=np.array([ 0.80064077,  2.64300842, -0.74912957])
W=np.array([[6.244998,2.88230677,-5.44435723],[0.,2.94827198,2.26990852],[0.,0.,0.45441135]]
n=W.shape[1]
x=np.zeros((1,n), dtype=np.float)
```

Proper solution should look like:

```
[-2.30857143  2.16571429 -1.64857143]
```

Comment: Can you give us a mathematical example ?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz you mean particular example I am focusing on? I've edited question to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach to use generic `n` and with one-loop -

```
def one_loop(y, W, n):
    out = np.zeros((1,n))
    for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
        sums = (W[i,i+1:]*out[0,i+1:]).sum()
        out[0,i] = (y[i] - sums)/W[i,i]
    return out
```

For performance, we can replace that sum-reduction step with a dot-product. Thus, `sums` could be alternatively computed like so -

```
sums = W[i,i+1:].dot(x[0,i+1:])
```

**Sample runs**

1) n = 3 :

```
In [149]: y
Out[149]: array([ 5.,  8.,  7.])

In [150]: W
Out[150]: 
array([[ 6.,  6.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  8.,  5.]])

In [151]: x = np.zeros((1,3))
     ...: x[0,2]=y[2]/W[2,2]
     ...: x[0,1]=(y[1]-W[1,2]*x[0,2])/W[1,1]
     ...: x[0,0]=(y[0]-W[0,2]*x[0,2]-W[0,1]*x[0,1])/W[0,0]
     ...: 

In [152]: x
Out[152]: array([[-0.9       ,  1.26666667,  1.4       ]])

In [154]: one_loop(y, W, n=3)
Out[154]: array([[-0.9       ,  1.26666667,  1.4       ]])
```

2) n = 4 :

```
In [156]: y
Out[156]: array([ 5.,  8.,  7.,  6.])

In [157]: W
Out[157]: 
array([[ 6.,  2.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  8.,  5.],
       [ 8.,  6.,  6.,  4.],
       [ 8.,  4.,  2.,  2.]])

In [158]: x = np.zeros((1,4))
     ...: x[0,3]=y[3]/W[3,3]
     ...: x[0,2]=(y[2]-W[2,3]*x[0,3])/W[2,2]
     ...: x[0,1]=(y[1]-W[1,3]*x[0,3]-W[1,2]*x[0,2])/W[1,1]
     ...: x[0,0]=(y[0]-W[0,3]*x[0,3]-W[0,2]*x[0,2]-W[0,1]*x[0,1])/W[0,0]
     ...: 

In [159]: x
Out[159]: array([[-0.22222222, -0.08333333, -0.83333333,  3.        ]])

In [160]: one_loop(y, W, n=4)
Out[160]: array([[-0.22222222, -0.08333333, -0.83333333,  3.        ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

One more take (now updated to the state-of-the-art provided by `Divakar` in another answer):

```
import numpy as np
y=np.array([ 0.80064077,  2.64300842, -0.74912957])
W=np.array([[6.244998,2.88230677,-5.44435723],[0.,2.94827198,2.26990852],[0.,0.,0.45441135]])
n=W.shape[1]
x=np.zeros((1,n), dtype=np.float)
```

> ```
> for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
>     x[0,i] = (y[i]-W[i,i+1:].dot(x[0,i+1:]))/W[i,i]
> print(x)
> ```

gives:

```
[[-2.30857143  2.16571429 -1.64857143]]
```

Answer (score 0):

My take

```
n=3
for k in range(n):
    print("s=y[%d]"% (n-k-1))
    s = y[n-k-1]
    for i in range(0,k):
        print("s - W[%d,%d]*x[0,%d]" % (n-k-1, n-i-1, n-i-1))
        s = s - W[n-k-1,n-i-1]*x[0,n-i-1]
    print("x[0,%d] = s/W[%d,%d]" % (n-k-1,n-k-1,n-k-1))
    x[0,n-k-1] = s/W[n-k-1,n-k-1]
print(x)
```

and without print statements

```
n=3
for k in range(n):
    s = y[n-k-1]
    for i in range(0,k):
        s = s - W[n-k-1,n-i-1]*x[0,n-i-1]
    x[0,n-k-1] = s/W[n-k-1,n-k-1]
print(x)
```

Output

```
s=y[2]
x[0,2] = s/W[2,2]
s=y[1]
s - W[1,2]*x[0,2]
x[0,1] = s/W[1,1]
s=y[0]
s - W[0,2]*x[0,2]
s - W[0,1]*x[0,1]
x[0,0] = s/W[0,0]
[[-2.30857143  2.16571429 -1.64857143]]
```